# Which file will be included when file exists in path and in local directory?

Tags: php, path, include, include-path

If I have a file in the path called inc.php and another file called inc.php in the same directory as index.php, and in index.php I place

```
include('inc.php')
```

Which file will be included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do an include, PHP searches through each entry in the include path checking for the existence of the file until it finds it, whereupon it includes the file from that entry in the include path.

Typically, the include path has . (the current working directory) as its first entry.

So unless you've changed the include_path so that . is no longer the first entry, it will include the file from the current working directory **because** it's also the first copy of the file that it finds in the include_path.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will go over your `include path` from left to right and for every folder check if a file named like this exists in that folder.

It will include the first one it finds.

If you include path looks like `".:/some/dir/:/some/other/dir"` it will look in the current folder first. Then check the others if it doesn't find anything.

**So usually it will include the file in the same folder.**

To see what your include path looks like use (f.e.) `echo ini_get("include_path");`

Answer (score 1):

As could be found in the [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function documentation :

> If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include() will finally
>   check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working
>   directory before failing.

So the `include_path` is searched first then the current directory (But your `include_path` could include the current directory if there is a `.` inside, maybe even first it depends on your server configuration).

Comment: So the local directory is the last place PHP will look?

Comment: As other said (and I added in my answer) the local directory COULD be in the include_path and could even be the first entry but that depends on your current settings.